# cast vector<unsigned char> to uint8_t*

Tags: c++, casting, stdvector

I have a function that requires `uint8_t*` as an input (unsigned char). However, I have my string saved as `vector<unsigned char>`. How to convert that to `uint8_t*` for my function to be able to accept?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in most of the case, `unsigned char` is same as `uint8_t`. if c++11 available, you can use this to conform it

```
static_assert(std::is_same<unsigned char, uint8_t>::value, "uint8_t is not unsigned char");
```

then you can just use [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get what you want

```
vector<unsigned char> vec = // your vector
uint8_t *data = vec.data();
```

Comment: Note that some -still popular- old compilers do not support `std::vector::data()`. In that case `&vec[0]` does the trick, provided the vector is not empty.